# Derivative of $x^T A(x) x$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How would the following derivative be expressed:

$$\frac{d}{d{\mathbf{x}}}\left(\mathbf{x}^T A(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{x}\right)$$.

$\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector, and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a square matrix which is symmetric. Each element of $A$ is a function of $\mathbf{x}$ I am having trouble visualizing the result of this general case.

**EDIT**

I am going about this very naively following a comment below.

$$\frac{d}{d{\mathbf{x}}}\left(\mathbf{x}^T A(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{x}\right) = \left(\frac{d}{d\mathrm{x}} \mathrm{x}^T\right)A(\mathrm{x}) \mathrm{x} + \mathrm{x}^T \frac{d}{d\mathrm{x}}(A(\mathrm{x})\mathrm{x}),$$

but then I end up with an inconsistent relationship involving one term that is a scalar:

$$\frac{d}{d{\mathbf{x}}}\left(\mathbf{x}^T A(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{x}\right) = A(\mathrm{x}) \mathrm{x} + \mathrm{x}^T \frac{d}{d\mathrm{x}}(A(\mathrm{x}))\, \mathrm{x} + \mathrm{x}^T A(\mathrm{x})$$

where the second term in the left hand side is the scalar.

Comment: Expand the expression and compute the derivative, then try to factor back.

Comment: @KBS I expanded the expression as suggested. The first and last terms of the right hand side, I can make sense of them being the same quantity. It is the middle term that I am having trouble with. Maybe my confusion is now more clear.

Comment: Hint: use the chain rule and the fact that $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^{n\times n}\times\Bbb R^n,(u,v,w)\mapsto u^Tvw$ (matrix product) is multilinear. $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cdot^T A(\cdot) \cdot\right)_x(h)=h^T A(x)x+ x^T\left(\left(\frac{dA}{d x}\right)_x(h)\right)x+x^T A(x)h.$$

Comment: The problem is that you are assuming $(d/dx) A(x)$ is a matrix when it is actually an order-3 tensor -- each element of A(x) has a "gradient vector" of length n.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to get to

$$ \begin{aligned}y & =\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}\boldsymbol{x}\\
\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}y & =\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}\boldsymbol{x}\right)\\
 & =\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)^{\intercal}{\rm A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\\
 & =\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\right)^{\intercal}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\\
 & =\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}^{\intercal}\right)^{\intercal}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}\\
 & ={\rm A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}{\rm A}
\end{aligned}$$

But you have to recognize that $\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)$ *is not* a matrix, but a rank-3 tensor. So $\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}$ is not a scalar, but a vector.

To understand $\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)$ consider the *i*-th column of ${\rm A}$ as a vector and calculate the jacobian matrix $${\rm J}_i = \frac{\partial{\rm A}_{i}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}$$

As a result, the *i*-th element of the vector $\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}}\left({\rm A}\right)\boldsymbol{x}$ is defined by the scalar $\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\left(\frac{\partial{\rm A}_{i}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}\right)\boldsymbol{x}$

Comment: Note that I switch the worlding from _i_-th row to _i_-th column. I did not work out the math exactly, but I think it suffices to think of ${\rm A}$ as a collection of column vectors ${\rm A}_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the matrix calculus.  It follows from linearity and the symmetry of $A(x)$ that

\begin{align} 
d(x^\intercal A(x)x) &=  dx^\intercal A(x)x + x^\intercal dA(x)x + x^\intercal A(x)dx \\
&= (A(x)x+A(x)^\intercal x)\cdot dx + x^\intercal (A’(x)dx)x \\
&= \left(2A(x)x + xx^\intercal : A’(x)\right)\cdot dx = \nabla\left(x^\intercal A(x)x\right)\cdot dx,
\end{align}

which gives the desired derivative automatically through duality.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Fundamentally, for a function $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ between normed spaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, its derivative $A$ at $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is the "best linear approximation" of $f$ about $x$. That is, $A$ is a (continuous) linear map from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ so that

$$ f(x + h) = f(x) + Ah + o(\|h\|_V) $$

as $ h \to 0$. In addition, if we fix some basis of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, then $A$ can be *represented* by a matrix.

> **Example.** In calculus and other areas, we often identify a linear map $L : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with a vector $\ell \in \mathbb{R}^n$ via the relation $ Lx = \ell^{\top}x$. If this identification is applied to the derivative $Df$ of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, then the resulting vector is called the *gradient* of $f$ and is denoted by $\nabla f$. That is, $ (Df)_x h = (\nabla f(x))^{\top} h $.

**2.** The above fundamental idea helps us identify the correct form of the "matrix representation" of a derivative. For example, if $x \mapsto A(x)$ is a symmetric-matrix-valued $C^1$-function, then

$$ f(x) = x^{\top}A(x)x $$

defines a $C^1$-function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Hence, its gradient $\nabla f$ at $x$ can be found by identifying the vector $\ell \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying

$$ f(x + h) = f(x) + \ell^{\top}h + o(\|h\|) $$

as $h \to 0$. Indeed, writing $\Delta A = A(x + h) - A(x)$ and noting that $\Delta A = o(1)$ as $h \to 0$, we get

\begin{align*}
f(x + h) - h(x)
&= (x + h)^{\top} A(x + h) (x + h) - x^{\top} A(x) x \\
&= (x + h)^{\top} (A(x) + \Delta A) (x + h) - x^{\top} A(x) x \\
&= h^{\top} A(x) x + x^{\top} \Delta A x + x^{\top} A(x) h + o(h).
\end{align*}

So it remains to convert the last expression into the form $\ell^{\top}h + o(h)$ for some vector $\ell \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This can be done by introducing the vector $B(x) = (b_1(x), \ldots, b_n(x))^{\top}$ where

$$ b_k(x) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} x_i x_j \frac{\partial A_{ij}(x)}{\partial x_k}. $$

Then $\Delta A = B(x)^{\top} h + o(h)$. With this and the identity $h^{\top} A(x) x = x^{\top} A(x) h$ together,

\begin{align*}
f(x + h) - h(x)
&= (B(x)^{\top} + 2x^{\top}A(x)) h + o(h) \\
&= (B(x) + 2A(x)x)^{\top} h + o(h).
\end{align*}

Therefore it follows that

$$ \nabla f(x) = B(x) + 2A(x)x. $$

I see no way of further simplying $B(x)$, except for invoking tensor operations. So this is probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: $B$ can be written nicely in terms of a vectorization of $A$ and the Kronecker product $x\otimes x$.